# How to cause debian to install from lower pin to get higher version?

Tags: apt, debian-installer, version

I am trying to install amdgpu-lib which has many dependencies from testing and possibly unstable. Not wanting to turn my entire system unstable, I created /etc/apt/preferences as follows:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

The pinning in /etc/apt/preferences prefers stable over testing over unstable, which are also available. Looking at libc6...

```
apt-cache policy libc6
```

outputs

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-13+deb11u6
  Candidate: 2.31-13+deb11u6
  Version table:
     2.36-9 650
        650 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        600 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.31-13+deb11u6 700
        700 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-13+deb11u5 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates/main amd64 Package
```

which states that libc6 version 2.36-9 is available from testing, even if not preferred.

```
apt-get install amdgpu-lib
```

reveals many dependency errors:

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm2-amdgpu : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-13+deb11u6 is to be installed
 ...
```

Meeting this requirement needs to install libc6 from testing. This may release a tree of upgrades from testing, but the resolution should exist and the result would be an OS that contains as little from testing and/or unstable as possible.

There are many dependency errors like this. Can apt handle this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` can handle such scenarios, but there are some caveats — notably, if you’ve set the default release anywhere, that takes precedence.

You can help `apt` by overriding the default release:

```
sudo apt install -t amdgpu-lib
```

You’ll end up with a setup somewhere in between Debian 11 and 12, which is generally not a great idea. At this point you might want to upgrade to Debian 12 wholesale, it’s due for release in less than two weeks and is frozen in preparation for that.

Another option is to contact AMD support... Note too that in many cases the built-in AMD drivers provide better performance than those available from the AMD web site.